# JAX-RS throws 415 error when using MultivaluedMap

Tags: jax-rs, websphere-liberty

```
 @POST
 @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
 @Produces("application/json")
 Response doSearch(   MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams, 
                      @Context UriInfo uriInfo);
```

I'm using JAX-RS and the above code always throws a 415 - Unsupported Media Type Error. Even though when I look at the header in the POST via firebug the content type is listed as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8". The form is being sent using dojos xhrpost.

I looked all over the place and cannot figure out why this isn't working. If I switch from using the MultiValuedMap to specifically stating all the @FormParams it works fine, but in my case I need to use the Map because I'm unsure of the number of parameters that the form will send.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance. If you need any further information please let me know.

Comment: it should work based on the information you posted. Can you confirm the import package for MultivaluedMap? Any reason your resource method is not public? do you see any errors in your server logs?

Comment: can you provide the exception stack? I'll take a wild guess and assume that org.apache.wink.server.internal.registry.ResourceRegistry is what's throwing the 415 WebApplicationException. If you can swing it, can you include your request that fails, as well? Thanks.

Comment: I had a similar problem. It turned out that only Firefox adds the parameter "charset" to the media type. All other browsers don't. So depending on the implementation you are using this might be the root cause. I suggest to test this with a different browser. If the problem cannot be recreated with other browsers, you can try to fix the Firefox issue separately.